# How to use relativelayout.setBackgroundDrawable() with a bitmap?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `RelativeLayout` object and want to dynamically change the background image with a dynamically created Bitmap object (it changes its color dynamically).

I saw that when I wanted to update the background image of the `RelativeLayout` object that I can only choose `setBackgroundDrawable()` which requires a Drawable object as a parameter.

My question is, how can I convert the dynamically created Bitmap object into a Drawable object?

Comment: is your image are come from local source or url?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`BitmapDrawable(obj)` convert Bitmap object into drawable object.

Try:

```
RelativeLayout relative = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative1);
Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(bit);
(view).setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: new BitmapDrawable(bitmap) is deprecated; use new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap)

Comment: This answer given more then before 3 years. So It might get highest chance to deprecate older methods as new methods came into picture. At that time it was right.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it by this way

```
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
RelativeLayout r;
r = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativelayout1);
ll.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
RelativeLayout rl=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main1);
Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(myImage);
rl.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

//Create Reference for RelativeLayout

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
```

//set Background to layout reference using the following method

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg);
layout.setBackground(drawable);
```

**Note:** R.id.rl is id of RelativeLayout

R.drawable.bg id the Image in drawable folder